# Latest update disabled my Internet

Tags: drivers, apt, wireless, updates, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on an ASUS TUF A15. I just ran an update, and some firmware was updated.

After I did that, my internet wouldn't connect. I tried turning it off and on again, and saw the following errors on reboot:

```
failed to send h2c command
failed to send h2c command
failed to send h2c command
failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
```

Now my wifi tray icon isn't even appearing, let alone connecting to my home network.

How can I fix this? As per `sudo lshw -class network`, my computer has a Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

Today's updates, as per `/var/log/apt/history.log` (almost sll on `amd 64 (5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1, automatic`):

```
Install:
linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-48-generic,
linux-image-5.8.0-48-generic, 
linux-headers-5.8.0-48-generic,
linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48,
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic
Upgrade:
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04,
brave-browser,
linux-libc-dev,
linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04,
isc-dhcp-common,
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04,
linux-generic-hwe-20.04,
isc-dhcp-client
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for 'lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lshw -c net'